# Cannot find where to change superglobal variables in this PHP site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

SSL has been applied to an PHP site but I'm getting "Mixed Content" errors on the console. To remove these error, I think I need to change the values inside the superglobal variable: $GLOBALS.site_url

I'm using FileZilla to access the site's files, and when I look at the index.tpl file, I find lines of code like these:

```
<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="{$GLOBALS.site_url}/templates/_system/main/images/css/form.css" />
<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="{image src="design.css"}" />

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="{$GLOBALS.site_url}/system/ext/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="{$GLOBALS.site_url}/system/ext/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="{$GLOBALS.site_url}/system/ext/jquery/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="{$GLOBALS.site_url}/system/ext/jquery/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="{$GLOBALS.site_url}/system/ext/jquery/jquery.autocomplete.pack.js"></script>
```

referencing $GLOBALS.site_url which it's probably set to HTTP without the security.

Could someone please suggest where I could find and change the value of this superglobal?

UPDATE:
Solution: I found an PHP file called "config.php" beside the Template folder. In this file, I simply changed the http to https.

Answer (score 1):

1) Try to search in the project by occurrences like $GLOBALS['site_url'] = and $site_url =

After additional investigation it looks like that you project can use smart job board software. You can check an official documentation if you really use it, but I think in this case "site_url" is saved in a database, and the easiest way will be to update the link at the smart job board settings page, of course if you have an access to the web site GUI.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Anton. I actually found an PHP file called "config.php" beside the Template folder. In this file, I simply changed the http to https.